# what are the words inside arrows('<', '>') in c++?

Tags: c++

I am going through C++ and cannot understand the items inside the arrow brackets.

```
ReadOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic<uint8_t, sizeof(readValue)> readChar(readCharUUID, readValue);
```

In this example, what does the contents inside the arrow brackets("uint8_t" & "sizeof(readValue)" mean?

Comment: Go to the bookstore, buy a book on C++, and turn to the chapter on "templates".

Comment: read the bit about templates

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - better to read the whole book

Comment: The keyword is ***templates***.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks a bunch!

Comment: No one downvoted this? Must be a Star Trek marathon on TV.

Comment: Come on man @nicomp he's trying to learn templates. Don't downvote it.

Comment: @DendiSuhubdy I didn't downvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably would want to read more on the documentation [here](https://docs.mbed.com/docs/ble-api/en/master/api/classReadOnlyArrayGattCharacteristic.html).

Where `<inbrackets>` means a `template<typename T , unsigned NUM_ELEMENTS>`. According to the ISO C++ (https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates)

> A template is a cookie-cutter that specifies how to cut cookies that
>   all look pretty much the same (although the cookies can be made of
>   various kinds of dough, they’ll all have the same basic shape). In the
>   same way, a class template is a cookie cutter for a description of how
>   to build a family of classes that all look basically the same, and a
>   function template describes how to build a family of similar looking
>   functions.
>
> Class templates are often used to build type safe containers (although
>   this only scratches the surface for how they can be used).

For example

Consider a container `class Array` that acts like an array of integers:

```
// This would go into a header file such as "Array.h"
class Array {
public:
  Array(int len=10)                  : len_(len), data_(new int[len]) { }
 ~Array()                            { delete[] data_; }
  int len() const                    { return len_;     }
  const int& operator[](int i) const { return data_[check(i)]; }  // Subscript operators often come in pairs
  int&       operator[](int i)       { return data_[check(i)]; }  // Subscript operators often come in pairs
  Array(const Array&);
  Array& operator= (const Array&);
private:
  int  len_;
  int* data_;
  int  check(int i) const
    {
      if (i < 0 || i >= len_)
        throw BoundsViol("Array", i, len_);
      return i;
    }
};
```

Repeating the above over and over for `Array` of `float`, of `char`, of `std::string`, of `Array`-of-`std::string`, etc, would become tedious. Instead, you add the `template<typename T>` before the class definition (the `T` can be any identifier you want, `T` is just the most commonly used one, especially in examples). Then, instead of using `int` or `float` or `char` where referring to the data type, you use `T` instead. Also, instead of just referring to the class as `Array`, it’s `Array<T>` when referring to the template, or `Array<int>`, `Array<float>`, etc. when referring to a specific instantiation.

```
// This would go into a header file such as "Array.h"
template<typename T>
class Array {
public:
  Array(int len=10)                : len_(len), data_(new T[len]) { }
 ~Array()                          { delete[] data_; }
  int len() const                  { return len_;     }
  const T& operator[](int i) const { return data_[check(i)]; }
  T&       operator[](int i)       { return data_[check(i)]; }
  Array(const Array<T>&);
  Array(Array<T>&&);
  Array<T>& operator= (const Array<T>&);
  Array<T>& operator= (Array<T>&&);
private:
  int len_;
  T*  data_;
  int check(int i) const {
    assert(i >= 0 && i < len_);
    return i;
  }
};
```

Read this book it will help [http://www.amazon.com/Template-Metaprogramming-Concepts-Techniques-Beyond/dp/0321227255](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321227255)

Comment: Thanks @tony-d yeah I forgot to insert the ticks

Comment: No worries - happy to help.  Nice answer!  Cheers.